# No texture when in render mode?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Forgive me if this is a silly/easy to figure out question, but I couldn't find anything... I tried the clear all restricted render option and had no luck so figured I would inquire here as google was of no help.

Camera view:
[image: camera view]

Post-rendering:
[image: camera view]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your plane have a material?

Comment: Yes, just one and I just added a bunch of modifiers to it

Comment: @airy, it can be very helpful to those who might want to try to help you, besides including the screenshots, to upload a copy of your file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), or a similar file hosting site, and provide a link to the uploaded file in your question.

Comment: @airy, welcome to Blender. After reading one of your comments in an answer, I suggest that you go to [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender/), and in the first category, "Learning", click on the item "on line courses", which contains links to two different on line courses covering blender, with the same cost, free. The material covered is substantially the same, and you can proceed at your own pace. I won't say that these courses make the learning curve for Blender any less steep, but they do add stairs and a handrail.

Answer (score -2):

Right click on your material,go to texture and check the empty boxes.Hope it help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: For some reason, right-clicking on it closes the whole program without and warning or anything.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) This answer is being flagged as low-quality. Could you add some more detail? Perhaps a screenshot indicating the location of the boxes you mention?

Comment: <img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/214cd3m.jpg" width="100" height="100">


I have none of those boxes to even check D: